# Azure Active Directory get token request http error

Tags: python, azure-active-directory

I'm using Active Directory Authentication library for python following the [documentation](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-python#acquire-token-with-client-certificate). Earlier on I managed to get the access_token through the [Acquire Token with Client Credentials sample](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-python/blob/dev/sample/client_credentials_sample.py#L46-L55):

```
import adal

RESOURCE_URI = 'https://<mydomain>.crm.dynamics.com'
AUTHORITY_URL = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant_id>"
CLIENT_ID = 'xxxx'  #application_id
CLIENT_SECRET = 'xxxx'

context = adal.AuthenticationContext(AUTHORITY_URL)
token = context.acquire_token_with_client_credentials(
    RESOURCE_URI,
    CLIENT_ID,
    CLIENT_SECRET)
print token
```

But I get an error message when I tried the [Acquire token and Refresh token sample](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-python/blob/dev/sample/refresh_token_sample.py#L47-L69)

```
context = adal.AuthenticationContext(AUTHORITY_URL)   
token = context.acquire_token_with_username_password(
    RESOURCE_URI,
    USERNAME,
    PASSWORD,
    CLIENT_ID)

print token

>>> adal.adal_error.AdalError: Get Token request returned http error: 401 and server response: {"error":"invalid_client","error_description":"AADSTS70002: The request body must contain the following parameter: 'client_secret or client_assertion'.........."correlation_id"......}
```

Answer (score 0):

> adal.adal_error.AdalError: Get Token request returned http error: 401 and server response: {"error":"invalid_client","error_description":"AADSTS70002: The request body must contain the following parameter: 'client_secret or client_assertion'.........."correlation_id"......}

There are two kinds of app we can register on Azure, native or web app. Based on the error message, it seems that you have register a confident app which requires provide its **client secret** to acquire the access token.

For this issue please register a native app instead of web app. Also the resource owner password credentials flow should be consider used carefully since this may leak the credentials. Refer the flows from link below:

[The OAuth 2.0 Authorization Framework - Authorization Grant](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-1.3)

Answer (score 0):

I suffered from the same error. 
In app registration section in azure active directory I registered the app as **web host/api**.
When I changed it to **native app** everything started to work fine.